# Matlab rotating image-point in 2D around arbitrary point

Tags: matlab, rotation, 2d, point

I want to rotate a point in 2D around an arbitrary point using Matlab. I am implementing following equation:
[image]

I have the following code. In my implementation

```
original = [eye_left(1); eye_left(2);1];    
m= size(im,2)/2  % width/2  (I want to rotate around the center of the image)
n= size(im,1)/2   % height/2
first = [1,0,-(size(im,2)/2); 0, 1,-(size(im,1)/2);0, 0, 1];
second = [cos(angle), -sin(angle),0; sin(angle), cos(angle), 0;0, 0, 1];
third = [1,0,size(im,2)/2; 0, 1,size(im,1)/2;0, 0, 1];

rotated = third* second* first * original;
```

But in the `rotated` variable the y-values is always soo far away from where I expect it to be...

Comment: for debug - trace the location of your point after each transformtation: plot the location after translation to origin `first*original`. Then after rotation about the origin: `second*first*original` and final the translation back `third*second*first*original`. Which stage causes the error in `y` coordinate?

Comment: original =

  649.3293,
  278.3167,
    1.0000,

my angle is : -3.1150,

and first * original : ans =

   -0.6707,
 -649.6833,
    1.0000,

Look how far it already has gone...both values

Comment: what is your image size? am I correct that the eye is at the lower part of the image?

Comment: 1300 * 1856. The eye is at the higher part of the image

Comment: I hope my answer helps, but I've had to guess that 'im' is a 2D array of points (trivial change if a 3D homogenous array) and that you want the center of the bounding box (trivial to switch to CoM). If I'm wrong, let me know and I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited*
My first answer was based on a misunderstanding of the question. I have included revised code. It now appears to be much more like your original. I get the result 
`1.0e+003 * [0.6475 1.6242]` for the transformed point. When plotted, this appears (as expected) almost perfectly reflected across the center.

**Working code**

```
clear all
close all

%% Points and angles (angle in radians)
angle = -3.1150
mypoint = [634 232] % Near top, middle

%% Sample data
load('mandrill', 'X', 'map');
im = uint8(X);
% Using Image Processing Toolkit to create an image 1300 wide by 1856 high
im = imresize(im, [1856 1300]); 

%% Calculate 'center' from extrema
m = size(im,2)/2     % width/2  (I want to rotate around the center of the image)
n = size(im,1)/2     % height/2

%% Tx matrices
first = [...
    1 0 -m;
    0 1 -n;
    0 0 1];

third = [...
    1 0 m;
    0 1 n;
    0 0 1];

second = [...
    cos(angle) -sin(angle) 0;
    sin(angle) cos(angle) 0;
    0 0 1];

%% Use homogenous coords
mp_hom = [mypoint 1]

%% Calculate (note because we premultiply,
rotated_hom = third* second* first* mp_hom';
rotated = rotated_hom'

%% Show it!
imshow(im)
hold on

plot(mypoint(:,1), mypoint(:,2), 'g+', 'MarkerSize', 12, 'LineWidth', 3)
plot (m, n, 'b*', 'MarkerSize', 12, 'LineWidth', 3)
plot(rotated(:,1), rotated(:,2), 'gx', 'MarkerSize', 12, 'LineWidth', 3)
```

Comment: im is just an image matrix (1300*1856). So to get the center of the image, I just do  size(im,2)/2 (number of columns divided by 2) and analogue for rows. Isnt that correct? Because with your method I am getting m=117 and n=118 , which cant be the center of the image, if the image is 1300*1856

Comment: Is im a 2D binary array, or other? It depends what the data is, and what you want exactly. If you want the center of the image bounds (assuming a rectangular image), then just [right - left, top - bottom]/2

Comment: Mmmm it's just a matrix :/ But I am getting an error in your code at: im_hom = [im ones(length(im),1)];    Do you maybe mean im*ones...?

Comment: If you are trying to rotate a 2D image matrix, like a regular picture, this won't do it for you I'm afraid. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you have a shape like the rectangle in your example, you can rotate it with my code. An image can't really be rotated the same way without difficulty. The rotation tells you where the old pixel ends up, but it is usually not an integer. What is done in practice is an inverse transform with interpolation.

Comment: If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, all of this can be done for you . . .

Comment: No, I have a point (634,232) in that image, that I want to rotate along the center of the image. Then I will have the new coordinates of the old point. That it what I want.

Comment: OK, so you have a single point `(634, 232)` that you want to rotate around the center of the image represented by `im`, by angle `angle`?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I want.

Comment: OK, fixed. This example shows Mandrill with the points placed on top. Note that I have used `mypoint` to represent the point to be rotated. I had to change your value for the example, because `[634 232]` is outside of the Mandrill picture! This code should work in your Matlab.

Comment: By the way, yes, you were right about the `m` and `n` values. I misunderstood your variables and what you were trying to do earlier.

Comment: With your technique I am still getting the exact same strange y-value which I was getting with my technique. If my point is eye_left =

  649.3293,  278.3167 ; and my angle is -3.1150 . How can the rotated point be rotated =

   1.0e+03 *

    (0.6334,    1.5775,    0.0010) . See the x-value is very close ok, but the y-value (1577.5) is tooo far away from 278.31... I dont understand this

Comment: Are you making the classic Matlab reversed-x-and-y mistake perhaps?

Comment: Or perhaps you're defining `theta` in degrees rather than radians. `-0.99*pi` **is** a rather odd number.

Comment: I was writing coords as matrices and just copied your brackets. LEt me fix my code. But to be clear, the image is wider than tall, and the point is about mid-way along x and near the top (ed)? Do you have the origin in bottom left, or top left?

Comment: There are two tricks in Matlab with images: 1) Rows come first, but that is y (you know that I see from m and n), and 2) The origin is top left, not bottom left (standard image coords from TV days)

Comment: Yes I know that. Widith=1300, Height=1856. The point ist mid-way along x and near to the top. Origin is top left

Comment: Ah, wait! I thought you had 1856 wide, 1300 high! But shouldn't break anything. Let me get answer version 438!

Comment: OK, my code still works for me, so not sure what is going wrong on your end, but I get 1.0e+003 * [0.6475 1.6242] as the new point now; similar to your answer earlier. But it appears correct.

Comment: I get a green '+' middle top, like you said. I get a green 'x' almost exactly opposite, which is what I would expect for a rotation of almost exactly pi radians.

Comment: Ah, I saw I was rounding. I get exactly your answer from earlier when I don't round, but that appears to be the correct answer. I guess I don't see the issue. A rotation of almost pi radians should take a point from the top and shove it on the bottom - unless you meant degrees, as suggested by beaker?